# chrome extension contentscript not receiving messages from background script long life connection

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm having a frustrating problem with message handling in Chrome,

I have a long lived connection running across my background page and popup page, the content page is able to send messages but not receive.

I've tired a number of methods but no joy.

Has anyone else encountered this?

content.js

```
coms = chrome.extension.connect({name: "coms"});
coms.onMessage.addListener(function(data) {
    console.log("com chatter");
});
```

popup.js

```
coms = chrome.extension.connect({name: "coms"});

chrome.extension.onConnect.addListener(function(port) {
   console.assert(port.name == "coms");
   port.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
      console.log("com chatter");
   });
});
```

Comment: Where are you sending messages, in your script?, you have added listeners and established connection!

Comment: Sorry bout the lateness, Australia day weekend :)

I only included the code I'm using to recieve calls

I'm sending messages with this 
    `coms.postMessage({frontend: "Message"});`

Comment: My mistake, I wasn't addressing the tab properly.

I needed to use chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabID,{.......});